# update trigger - update stock level based on count of rows changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to keep track of stock levels using `AFTER UPDATE` triggers in SQL Server 2019.

I have this table `Units` (unique items with serial numbers), table simplified for this example:

| UnitID | ProductID | SalesOrderDetailID | SerialNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Null | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | Null | 34 |
| 3 | 1 | Null | 56 |
| 4 | 2 | Null | 78 |
| 5 | 2 | Null | 90 |
| 6 | 2 | Null | 99 |

And this table for `Stock`:

| ProductID | StockSell | Updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1.1.2022 10:10:00 |
| 2 | 45 | 3.10.2022 22:48:05 |

I want to use an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to update the `Stock` table when I assign a `SalesOrderDetailID` to a `Unit`. I managed to write the trigger for a single row update using parameters, but that's not good.

I have this at the moment:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UnitUpdated
ON tbl1Units
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl1Stock
    SET StockSell = StockSell - 1
    FROM tbl1Stock S    
    JOIN INSERTED I ON S.ProductID = I.ProductID
    JOIN DELETED D ON I.UnitID = D.UnitID
    WHERE I.SalesOrderDetailID IS NOT NULL 
      AND D.SalesOrderDetailID IS NULL
END
```

The problem is that when I assign `SalesOrderDetailID` to more `Units` in a single operation, the `Stock` level only reduces by 1, which after a short investigation is quite obvious because of the `SET StockSell = StockSell - 1` statement.

How should I edit this statement for it to deal with bulk updates correctly?

Using the example above, if I scan units 4, 5 and 6 into a particular sales order and edit the `Units` table in bulk, I want the `Stock Level` for `Product = 2` to change from 45 to 42.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that stock value is always *meant* to be a count of the number of rows for each product with a `NULL` `SalesOrderDetailId`, why store it at all? Running an aggregate will *always be correct* and doesn't require any of this manual bookkeeping.

Comment: I may have oversimplified the model. This is not _always_ the case, each Unit has quite complex life cycle and stock value is dependant on multiple factors. I need to have a complete control over the stock levels based on many conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the updates may affect more than one `ProductID`, you need to `GROUP BY` `ProductID` before joining to `tbl1Stock`.

```
UPDATE S
SET    StockSell = S.StockSell - I.Cnt
FROM   tbl1Stock S    
       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT I.ProductID, Cnt = count(*)
           FROM   INSERTED I 
           WHERE  I.SalesOrderDetailID IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY I.ProductID
       ) I ON S.ProductID = I.ProductID
```

Note : I didn't include the `DELETED` as I don't quite understand your logic on `DELETED.SalesOrderDetailID IS NULL`